# Displaying the number of entries in a category

Tags: categories, channel

Is there a way to select channel, list out the categories assigned to that channel and then the number of entries in each category?

What I want is something link the below:

Category 1 - 100 entries
Category 2 - 70 entries
etc...

I've tried this, but dosn't get me what I want:

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="news"}
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">{category_name} ({exp:channel:entries category="{category_id}" dynamic="no"}{absolute_results}{/exp:channel:entries})</a>
                  </li>
                  {/exp:channel:categories}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can do this by making simple template and embed.

Create one template `template_name.html` in your template group and insert below code.

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="channel_name" disable="category_fields"}
    *******************************************************
    <br>

    Category Name : {category_name}
    <br>

    {!-- including the embed which have channel entry code --}
    {embed="template_group_name/.embed_name" cat_id="{category_id}"}

    *******************************************************
    <br>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Now create one embed `.embed_name.html` into that template group. And insert below code.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name"
disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks|relationships" dynamic="no" 
category="{embed:cat_id}"}

    {if count == 1}
    Total Entries = {total_results}<br>
    {/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I hope this will definitely works for you.

Answer (score 1):

this feature is not supported Natively
you can use the query module for this or third party

http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/examples/example4

This add-on has been ported to EE3 / EE4 compatibility - though labelled as a beta the updated version works well.  Find the updated version discussed in [this thread](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/gwcode-categories/viewthread/15375), and the downloadable version [here](http://gwcode.com/gwcode_categories_3beta.zip).

Comment: Hi Akwad, thanks for your help.  It's an EE 4 site, so it's a shame that's not being ported, it would have being perfect.

Comment: thats why I am moving away from EE
EE is fading out